# Can a Great Unclean One ruin regions immediately on summoning?

Tags: chaos-in-the-old-world

The Great Unclean One upgrade card says

> Immediately place two corruption tokens in a region when you summon a
>   Great Unclean One there.

These corruption tokens appear outside of the normal Corruption phase, so it's not clear how they interact with region ruination. The rules (p.19) say

> To resolve the corruption step... players count the total number of corruption tokens in the region... If this total is 12 or more, that region is RUINED.
>
> Then each player who placed at least one corruption token in that region during this corruption step immediately scores the same number of victory points indicated for ruiners on that ruination card.

1. If placing the Great Unclean One pushed the total number of corruption tokens to 12 or more, is the region immediately ruined? Or does ruination not occur until the Corruption phase?
2. The Nurgle player's corruption tokens were not placed during the corruption step. Does the Nurgle player count as a ruiner for VPs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/chaos_in_the_old_world/FAQ/CitOW_FAQ-v2_web.pdf) it says:

> Errata
>   Rulebook (pages 19–20)
>   If a region is ruined, each player who placed at least
>   one corruption token in that region during this round
>   immediately scores the number of victory points
>   indicated for ruiners on that ruination card

So that means the Nurgle player would count as a ruiner if that region was ruined that turn. However, ruination is only checked in the ruination phase, and so the region would not be ruined immediately.